# How to increment a variable when a number is found in the column using R

Tags: r

I have a data frame as shown below,

```
Col1
34
45
67
80
89
87
80
79.9
94
89
54
88
```

**Question**
I need to have another variable called `Incremental_count` which increments the value when ever it finds value in the col1 above 80 as shown below

```
col1    Incremental_count
34          0
45          0
67          0
80          1
89          1
87          1
80          1
79.9        0
94          2
89          2
54          0
88          3
56          0
76          0
83          4
55          4
```

Kindly let me know the script.

**Updated Question**
I need to have another variable called `Incremental_count` which increments the value when ever it finds value in the col1 above 80 and has to retain the incremented value to the below rows though the value in col1 in less than 80, as shown below

```
col1    Incremental_count
34          0
45          0
67          0
80          1
89          1
87          1
80          1
79.9        1
94          2
89          2
54          3
88          3
56          3
76          3
83          4
55          4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rle` i.e. run-length-encoding from `base R` to get the expected output

```
df1$Incremental_count <- inverse.rle(within.list(rle(df1$Col1 > 80), 
             values[values] <- seq_along(values[values])))
df1
#   Col1 Incremental_count
#1  34.0                 0
#2  45.0                 0
#3  67.0                 0
#4  80.0                 0
#5  89.0                 1
#6  87.0                 1
#7  80.0                 0
#8  79.9                 0
#9  94.0                 2
#10 89.0                 2
#11 54.0                 0
#12 88.0                 3
```

#### Update

Based on the updated example in OP's post

```
df2$Incremental_count <- with(df2, cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(col1 < 80) < 0)))
df2$Incremental_count
#[1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c(34, 45, 67, 80, 89, 87, 80, 79.9, 94, 
89, 54, 88)), .Names = "Col1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))

df2 <- structure(list(col1 = c(34, 45, 67, 80, 89, 87, 80, 79.9, 94, 
89, 54, 88, 56, 76, 83, 55)), .Names = "col1", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: And If I have to maintain the incremented value for the below rows instead of putting 0 then what changes should I have to make?

Comment: @Anup Could you update your post with what exactly you expected

Comment: @akrun This is really cool, thanks! Even after reading up on it, I don't quite understand two items in your code - the `within.list` part : is that just a variation on `with()`, or what does it do? I couldn't locate much documentation on this. Similarly, the second part of the argument to `within.list` is not quite clear to me - you are assigning the result of `seq_along` to `values[values]` but what exactly does this tell the function to do? If you have a minute, any pointers are much appreciated!

Comment: @patrick Thanks, the output of `rle` is a `list` and it has methods to extract or do some modification using `within.list`  It should be a modification of `within` that applies to `list`

Comment: @akrun Done!!!! Bang on!!  Code works as required, Thanks a lot Master.